# iio Engine game development tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have recently wanted to develop a game with iio engine. However, I guess there is not enough resources to do so. I have tried tutorials on http://iioengine.com/tutorials/ but they are somewhat difficult to implement. Hence, can anybody tell me basics of the iio engine and simple tricks for game development.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I really cannot get it. I just ask for help for development tricks with iioengine. What's the problem?

Comment: No problem, your question is simply off-topic and not a fit for SO.

Comment: ok. please help me to improve my question? I need to know foundations of iio engine. that's all.

Comment: recommendation would be to find a forum that deals with the platform you're interested in.

Comment: yeah maybe. thanx for suggestion Kevin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an article from hacker news on iio engine game development. As it says, the most important thing is the io object which is given to the constructor of the application as follows.

```
YourGame = function(io){};
iio.start(YourGame,'canvasId')
```

After receiving the io object, you can easily add or delete objects to the canvas as follows.

```
var grid = io.addObj(new iio.Grid(0,0,3,3,150));
io.rmvObj(grid);
```

Anyway, you can have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.yusufaytas.com/implementing-html5-bomberman/).